# Got the error code "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction')" while trying to deploy to the goerli test network

Tags: javascript, hardhat

Here is my hardhat.config.js code

```
// hardhat.config.js

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("dotenv").config()

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

const GOERLI_URL = process.env.GOERLI_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.GOERLI_URL || "https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/PT8BEXCUKwsfvcBz8y3g7A2V7LdhUKQA",
      accounts: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
    }
  }
};
```

And my deploy.js script:

```
// scripts/deploy.js

const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  // We get the contract to deploy.
  const BuyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("BuyMeACoffee");
  const buyMeACoffee = await BuyMeACoffee.deploy();

  await buyMeACoffee.deployed();

  console.log("BuyMeACoffee deployed to:", buyMeACoffee.address);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I really do not know how to get it sorted and it pretty much has left me in a loop.
Please help. Thank You
I am pretty much new to using hardhat and npm. My current node v16.13.1 (npm v8.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the hardhat.config file instead of accounts:process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, it should have been accounts:[process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]

Comment: Used your suggestion and got the error message:

Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid account: #0 for network: goerli - Expected string, received undefined

Comment: do a console.log(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY) it will probably return undefined?

Check if you formatted your .env variable without any whitespace (be aware to exclude the .env from any auto formatters like prettier)

this will work:
PRIVATE_KEY=0xabc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc1

this will give you an error
PRIVATE_KEY = 0xabc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc1